# How to correctly implement generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a little problem. 
Below is a code sample. How can I have a variable like `testVar` that can take `ITest<T>`? Obviously I get an cast error.  Is there some way I can fully use the generic interface without casting?
I tried to make `T` covariant `(out T)`, but that's not possible due to the `ResultEventArgs`.

```
using System;

namespace InterfaceGenericFunApp
{
    public class ResultEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
    {
        public T Result { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITest<T>
    {
        event EventHandler<ResultEventArgs<T>> ResultReceived;
    }

    public class TestClass : ITest<string>
    {
        public event EventHandler<ResultEventArgs<string>> ResultReceived;
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static ITest<object> testVar; 

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testVar = new TestClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

C# generics are somewhere between Java's generics and C++'s templates. In Java, this would be easy - you'd just use `ITest<?>`. In C# and C++, this is impossible.

While Java's generics only really exist at compile-time (basically, to allow additional static type checks), C#'s are "real" in the runtime as well. For example, imagine a simple generic class that's nothing but a wrapper over another value:

```
class Test<T>
{
  public T Value;
}
```

In Java, the field will always be of type `Object` - `Test<?>`, `Test<String>` and `Test<Integer>` are exactly the same type in runtime.

In C#, the field will be *exactly* the type specified in the generic type argument. This is a *huge* difference - for example, it means that if you use a value-type, it isn't going to be boxed. It also means that `Test<?>` doesn't make any sense - different instantiations of the generic type can have entirely different memory layouts. This also means that only the usual variance is allowed: a child type can be assigned to a parent type, but not vice versa - a child type can be passed instead of a parent type, but not vice versa.

This explains your trouble with making the interface covariant - simply put, it *isn't* covariant. `EventHandler` is *passing* your value rather than returning it, so you can only ever pass child types, not parent types (e.g. it's fine to pass `string` instead of `object`, but not `object` instead of `string`). The only variance possible is contravariance - you could use `ITest<string>` to store an instance of `ITest<object>`. `Func<T>` is covariant, while `Action<T>` is contravariant. And of course, `Func<T, U>` is contravariant with respect to `T` and covariant with respect to `U`.

How you can solve your actual problems depends entirely on what your problem actually *is*. For example, if you're only building a collection of objects, you could use a non-generic interface that exposes whatever you need. You can also manually cast the value to a `ITest<Whatever>` - though that obviously means losing type safety to an extent. Or, if you only need to work with specific instantiations at any time, you can work with each type separately like so:

```
foreach (var component in Components.OfType<ITest<Whatever>>()) ...
```

**EDIT:**

In your case, it seems that you want to do some action based on the result of some dialog which isn't modal, otherwise you'd simply use `ShowDialog` and complete synchronously, right?

This calls for some form of asynchronicity, of course. The simplest being a simple delegate - let's suppose you have a method `ShowDialogAsync` on each of your individual dialogs, taking a function which in turn takes an argument supplied by the dialog when it is confirmed. For example, a dialog that returns a single string could have a method like this:

```
public static void ShowDialogAsync(Action<string> action) { ... }
```

The key here is that the dialog *knows* the exact delegate type you supply, and the caller does as well - no need to store a "global" field anywhere.

The call could look something like this:

```
UsernameDialog.ShowDialogAsync(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

So whenever the dialog completes, the strongly typed delegate is invoked with the argument taken from the dialog's textbox (for example). The entire dialog could look something like this:

```
private readonly Action<string> _action;

private UsernameDialog(Action<string> action)
{
  _action = action;
}

public static void ShowDialogAsync(Action<string> action) 
{
  var dialog = new UsernameDialog(action);
  dialog.Show();
}

// I wouldn't actually bind this to a button click, this is just an example
public void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _action(tbxUsername.Text);
  Close();
}
```

If you've ever seen `Task` or `await` before, the pattern here should be obvious - indeed, it is trivial to make `ShowDialogAsync` return a `Task<string>` instead of accepting `Action<string>`, allowing you to do this:

```
var username = await UsernameDialog.ShowDialogAsync();
```

And indeed,

```
UsernameDialog.ShowDialogAsync().ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result));
```

The two approaches are quite symmetric - the main difference is in the thinking;  `Task<T>` "pulls" the result, while `Action<T>` "pushes" the result: though it's obvious that either can be used to do the opposite as well; in the `ContinueWith` sample, I've used `Task<T>` to *push* a value. Pulling a value from `Action<T>` is also quite easy:

```
string result = null;
UsernameDialog.ShowDialogAsync(i => { result = i; });
```

Though it should be noted that this only makes sense if the `Action<T>` is actually executed before `ShowDialogAsync` exits - `Task<T>` handles this by waiting for the result when you use `Task<T>.Result`; you could do the same with the action by using something like this:

```
string result = null;
var waitHandle = new ManualResetEventSlim();
UsernameDialog.ShowDialogAsync(i => { result = i; waitHandle.Set(); });

waitHandle.Wait();
```

Obviously, this is a contrived example - there's little point in using asynchronous callbacks just to force them to be synchronous - but it should illustrate the symmetry. In the real world, you'd simply return a `Task<T>`, or use the asynchronous callback.

The key point in all four of those examples is that you *never* needed any global state to handle the dialog - whether you treat it synchronously or asynchronously. This allows you to always work with known types whenever you actually need to - when you show a dialog, it's a known dialog, and the arguments are known; when you handle the callback (or promise), you again do so in the piece of code that actually knows what it means.

Let's say that you need to show a dialog that allows you to change the username in another form - even using the manual callback, this is as easy as

```
UsernameDialog.ShowDialogAsync(userName => { lblUsername.Text = username; });
```

The trick here is the use of a *closure* - basically, `lblUsername` (to be more exact, `this`, i.e., the form) was silently "passed" along with the callback, without having to be an explicit argument of the `Action` delegate!

This is entirely general, and allows you to program anything you want using functions (seriously, we're talking about math theorems here - any imperative program can be converted into a functional one - and delegates are little more (or less) than functions).

I'd stick to returning `Task<...>` if it makes sense - callbacks are fine, but it's quite easy to end up in a callback hell. Using `Task<...>` along with `await` is *much* easier.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. The problem is that I have a single class variable (testVar in this example) that can be IDialog<Anything> the type is result of an event. "testVar" change during runtime because in the actual application it stores a ViewModel for a dialog in a WPF application.

Comment: @KrisThomsen There is no way to make that typesafe. Why are you storing the field in the first place? Passing functions is as easy as passing any other value, there shouldn't be anything preventing you from keeping all the generic instances local, where you know *exactly* the generic type involved.

Comment: I think you have a point here. Could you maybe create a small example of what you mean?

Comment: @KrisThomsen Expanded a bit; a more specific solution would require me to know more about your code, but this should give you the general gist of the ideas.

Comment: Thanks @Luaan this was great help :) Had to make some small changes due to me using .NET 3.5. The turning point was the ManualResetEvent-thing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KrisThomsen Yeah, it's relatively easy to implement your own (simple and relatively inefficient) `Task` - for example, continuations are easily implemented using `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` ("run callback when a wait handle is signalled"), and waiting is as simple as calling `Wait`/`WaitOne` on the wait handle directly. Proper error handling is probably the trickiest part, especially in the continuations - you do need to be a bit careful, as with any asynchronous/multi-threaded programming.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple way to make it work.

Your variable `testVar` promises that I get a class that has an event that has an event arg where I can set the `Result` to *any object*.

What you want to assign is a class where in the end I can *only* assign a `string` to the `Result` property. That does not work with the promise above to be able to set any object.

You may be able to work this out if all parts of `T` are read-only, because reading an object *can be* reading a string. But writing is problematic.

Comment: To be more exact, it's fine to use covariance for reading, and contravariance for writing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

```
public class Program
{
    private static ITest<string> testVar;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        testVar = new TestClass();
    }
}
```

You can't have `ITest<object>`, because a `string` is a specification of `object`. You have to set `ITest` to `string`.

EDIT:
You could also make TestClass generic:

```
public class TestClass<T> : ITest<T>
{
    public event EventHandler<ResultEventArgs<T>> ResultReceived;
}

public class Program
{
    private static ITest<string> testVar;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        testVar = new TestClass<string>();
    }
}
```